# node.js serialization without package

Tags: node.js, serialization

I want to send an array of objects from node.js to browser javascript. The way I guess it is serializing it, sending through by response.write, then de-serializing at the browser side. Is my guess right? Any other way without using package? Question is how to implement it, serialize at server and de-serialize at browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This simple script demonstrates the concept. It works perfectly:

```
var body = '<!DOCTYPE html>'+ 
    '<html lang="en">'+
        '<head>'+
            '<meta charset="UTF-8">'+
            '<title>lab</title>'+
        '</head>'+
        '<body>'+
            '<script>%SCRIPT%</script>'+
        '</body>'+
    '</html>';

// array foo is defined in node.js server
var foo = [];
foo[0] = 'hello';
foo[1] = 'world';
// or it can be defined as bellow
foo = [{id: 4, text: "Hello four"}, {id: 9, text: "Hello nine"}];

// array foo is passed to client browser
var str = '';
str += 'var obj = '+JSON.stringify(foo)+';';
str += 'console.log(obj);';

body = body.replace('%SCRIPT%', str);
response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
response.end(body);
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are right, this is what [JSON](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) born to. You can serialize it with `JSON.stringify` at the server and des-serialize it with `JSON.parse` at the client side.

```
var array = [{ id: 4, text: "Hello four" }, { id: 9, text: "Hello nine" }];

res.end(JSON.stringify(array));
```

And in the client, for example:

```
var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

xmlHttp.open("GET", '/routeServingTheObject', false);
xmlHttp.send(null);

var object = JSON.parse(xmlHttp.responseText);
```

This without using any common library, like [jQuery](https://github.com/jquery/jquery). Note that JSON doesn't support things like for example function. To will need to send a javascript script to the client instead of a JSON. Nevertheless to do any complicated task I would suggest you some form of template system or library like [socket.io](http://socket.io/), It's usually a better way to do things at least if you don't have enormous  amounts of time to create your own tools.